# Using jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter to insert records

Tags: spring-integration

Is it good practice to use a jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter to insert records?

I have been playing around with using an insert statement that has a select from clause to create records.  It works, but a "Dispatcher has no subscribers" error message is logged.

Is there a more appropriate alternative approach?  If not, is there a good way to avoid the no subscribers error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jdbc outbound-gateway instead.

It's certainly an anti-pattern to use the inbound adapter for that, but setting the channel to `"nullChannel"` should work.